# Duplicate Symbols when using pod "TensorFlowLite" and pod "MediaPipeTasksVision" on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I am trying to use the new mediapipe Vision solution (handLandlmarker) with another custom ML model TFlite in my application, but when trying to add pod "MediaPipeTasksVision" it generate duplicate symbols with the pod "TensorFlowLiteSwift" already used in the project.

Here is the Podfile in my application :

```
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'
pod 'MediaPipeTasksVision'
end
```

here is the error :

```
Duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateGetThreadPool' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateWeightsCacheFinalizeHard' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorCopy' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryInterpreterSettingsGetSubgraphInfo' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryConversionMetadataGetNumModelOptimizationModes' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorResizeMaybeCopy' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetrySubgraphInfoGetQuantizations' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateOptionsDefault' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateWeightsCacheDelete' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryGpuDelegateSettingsGetBackend' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateDelete' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteOpaqueDelegateCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetrySubgraphInfoGetNumQuantizations' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteOpaqueDelegateGetData' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorReset' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateWeightsCacheFinalizeSoft' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryInterpreterSettingsGetNumSubgraphInfo' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteFloatArrayFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorDataFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteSparsityFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayEqual' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryInterpreterSettingsGetConversionMetadata' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateCreateWithThreadpool' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayEqualsArray' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryGpuDelegateSettingsGetNumNodesDelegated' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteDelegateCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayGetSizeInBytes' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTensorRealloc' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTypeGetName' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteTelemetryConversionMetadataGetModelOptimizationModes' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1215](telemetry_setting_internal.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateWeightsCacheCreateWithSize' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateWeightsCacheCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteFloatArrayGetSizeInBytes' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[592](xnnpack_delegate.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteIntArrayCopy' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteQuantizationFree' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteFloatArrayCreate' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
duplicate symbol '_TfLiteOpaqueDelegateDelete' in:
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRISContact-dgqmbmbgwvhrirbfhlygyvgrnmmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TensorFlowLiteC/Core/TensorFlowLiteC.framework/TensorFlowLiteC
    /Users/abdelrahmanmohasseb/Documents/IRIS-R&D/IRISContact/Pods/MediaPipeTasksCommon/frameworks/graph_libraries/libMediaPipeTasksCommon_device_graph.a[1236](common.o)
ld: 41 duplicate symbols
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

is there anyone has the same problem ?

I tried different versions of pod "MediapipeTasksVisions" but got no luck in resolving the duplicate symbols